# jQuery sub-menu mouse hover anomalous behavior

Tags: jquery, toggle, submenu

I have a problem for which I hope you can help me.

On the website I'm building, I use a jQuery function to show and hide a sub-menu when the mouse hovers over it with a fading effect.

This is the code:

```
(function($) {

$('.menu-item-has-children').hover(  function() {    $('.sub-menu', this).stop().fadeToggle(400);  },);         

    })( jQuery );
```

The issue that occurs is as follows: when I click on one of the sub-menu items, I am naturally redirected to the corresponding page of the clicked link.

However, if I press the "back" button in the browser from that page, I find myself with the sub-menu still open, even though I am not hovering over it with the mouse.

If I then hover over it again, the menu closes.

Basically, the hover function is reversed.

I asked for support from Chat GPT, which suggested this modification:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').hover(  function() {
    $('.sub-menu', this).stop().fadeToggle(400);
  },
  function() {
    $('.sub-menu', this).stop().fadeToggle(400);
  }
);
```

This actually fixes it, but there's still a small problem.

Now when I click on "back" in the browser the hover function is no longer inverted.

However, after pressing "back", as soon as the page loads, the sub-menu is still open (as I left it when I clicked on the link).

It closes correctly when I hover from the back button to anywhere on the web page with the mouse.

So the functioning is correct and it is no longer reversed, but the only drawback that I have described remains.

Can you help me solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: please copy your code snippet and html to jsfiddle.net then it will be easy to see the problem

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.